# Fetch list of taxes from WooCommerce REST API (v2) using PHP

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, tax

I need to fetch taxes from the WooCommerce REST API using PHP. I am using **API version 2**.

This is the function that I tried :

```
$client->taxes->get(null, array( 'filter[limit]'=>100000 ))
```

But it is not getting any result. It is giving this error :

```
"No route was found matching the URL and request method
[woocommerce_api_no_route] 404"
```

Tried everything and searched everywhere but could find any solution. 
An example is given in the API documentation like this only but I could not find out the related PHP code.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks